# Is there an abbreviation for "have a nice lunch"?

Tags: abbreviations

Is there a short form of "have a nice lunch"?
I'd guess there should be one for an informal occasion like between friends.

How would you say "have a nice lunch" in situations like:

1. to your toddler
2. to your co-worker
3. to your spouse

Would it be the same "have a nice lunch"? or would you say it differently per situation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the context you’re saying this in? I can’t recall having said it, ever, so maybe it’s not translating well.

Comment: I just would like to know if I can shorten "have a nice lunch" and how to say it in different ways

Comment: It isn't a standard phrase in English like the French _Bon appetit_, so there are no rules about saying it in different situations. "Enjoy your meal" would be another possible version.

Comment: Do you mean shorter as in, less than four syllables to say? Like a 'cheers!' equivalent for food? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can simply say:

> Enjoy!

This is informal and quite flexible: you can use it in almost any situation where someone is about to do something and you want to express a wish that the thing goes pleasantly.